# 2D plot with Z axis data in python

Tags: python, plot, 2d

I'd like to plot from this data(file):

```
# file name: c7.csv
... 
...
...
Scan Start
2d statistical,-32,-24,-16,-8,0,8,16,24,32
120,0.254592,0.195414,0.00428721,0.0114557,0.0147995,0.0458237,0.0924488,0.161643,0.286074
112,0.251826,0.141975,3.81476e-07,1.33516e-06,2.67033e-06,0.000362783,0.0192802,0.126411,0.255406
104,0.251825,0.127342,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,8.16358e-05,0.121867,0.251922
96,0.251825,0.125952,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.0998646,0.251903
88,0.251825,0.123279,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.0703892,0.251903
80,0.251825,0.0669492,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.0437135,0.251903
72,0.251825,0.0133867,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.0134152,0.251845
64,0.251847,0.00226196,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.000735103,0.249137
56,0.254034,5.14992e-06,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,5.72213e-07,0.235424
48,0.265368,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.219798
40,0.282969,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.198044
32,0.333191,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.172414
24,0.363716,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.165892
16,0.343822,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.168372
8,0.307494,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.186618
0,0.297795,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.196873
-8,0.283094,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.191286
-16,0.305736,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.174678
-24,0.360888,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.173295
-32,0.347627,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.179868
-40,0.306325,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.189885
-48,0.287914,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.2148
-56,0.259855,1.02998e-05,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.229949
-64,0.252141,0.00180457,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.000303082,0.247241
-72,0.251826,0.0219065,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.0110576,0.251671
-80,0.251825,0.0676513,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.0373565,0.251922
-88,0.251825,0.121092,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.0683341,0.251903
-96,0.251825,0.125971,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.0962393,0.251903
-104,0.251825,0.126107,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,3.81476e-07,0.000229076,0.114732,0.251941
-112,0.251831,0.131269,2.28885e-06,2.67033e-06,4.63493e-05,0.000350958,0.0314566,0.13105,0.260355
-120,0.269835,0.181753,0.00982261,0.0178109,0.0331482,0.0722836,0.110299,0.175774,0.299987
Scan End
...
...
...
```

Result should seems:

[image]

1st, I read in data from .csv file (c7.csv)

```
with open('c7.csv', newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  data = list(reader)
```

2nd, I find *begin* and *end* place from input data

```py
cnt_start = 0;
while(data[cnt_start][0] != 'Scan Start'):
  cnt_start+=1

cnt_end = 0;
while(data[cnt_end][0] != 'Scan End'):
  cnt_end+=1
```

3rd, I grab data from 'Scan Start' to 'Scan End' from input data with *begin* and *end* place

```py
vals = []
for i in range(cnt_start +1 , cnt_end):
  vals.append(data[i])
```

and remove str '2d statistical'

```py
vals[0].pop(0)
```

4th, since data is *string* type, I convert it to float type

```py
for i in vals:
  for j in i:
    j = float(j)
```

5th, I extract row scale and column scale from previous data out

```
column_vals = []
column_vals = vals.pop(0)

row_vals = []
for i in vals:
  row_vals.append(i.pop(0))
```

Finally, I show data output for plot needed datas

```
print(column_vals) # x scale
print(row_vals) # y scale
print(vals) # z data
```

[All of code above in here](https://trinket.io/python/e60fde3645)
(If needed package has been installed, this code could be executed)

Needed data seems has be ready.

How do I do next step (plot 2D and add scale x_data, y_data)?

Comment: Your Question has to be self-contained. Meaning all the information needs to be within this Question itself. A link is not sufficient. Please edit and include your code here.

Comment: Hi @Scratte : I've fixed.